# Server Error (500) na Heroku usando Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku, servidor

Quando tento acessar meu site hospedado na Heroku, ele retorna a mensagem: "Server Error (500)".

*heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=quiz-py.herokuapp.com request_id=ef039cdc-8d6a-4735-9a91-942d546c5d06 fwd="170.79.165.63" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=366 protocol=https*

**settings:**

```py
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["https://quiz-py.herokuapp.com/", "127.0.0.1"]
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**wsgi.py:**

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

#application = get_wsgi_application()

from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

**Procfile:**

web: gunicorn app.wsgi --log-file -

Não sei o motivo, pesquisei bastante porém não consegui achar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Então, eu estava com o mesmo problema e consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

Adicionei a seguinte linha ao arquivo *settings.py*:

**DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1**

Depois criei uma pasta na raiz do projeto com o nome **'static'** e copiei os arquivos estáticos para ela.

(**Não movi**, mas talvez funcione se mover também).

Ah, depois eu fiz o migrate do model, com o comando:

**heroku run python manage.py migrate**

Depois fiz o deploy novamente, usando os comandos do git e funcionou normalmente.

P.S.: Os dados do banco de dados local (sqlite3) não sobem junto com o projeto.

Deve existir uma maneira de subir tais dados, mas ainda não pesquisei sobre.

Answer (score 0):

Cara, comigo estava dando o mesmo erro (500), e no meu caso o problema foi com os arquivos estáticos no código html que referenciei errado.

A forma que eu fiz e estava dando erro:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '../static/css/login.css' %}">
```

Referenciando da forma **correta**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/login.css' %}">
```

Isso serve não só para importar o css como pra os outro arquivos estáticos (imagens e JavaScript)

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles"

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Espero ter ajudado alguém !!